# 'mongod wiredTiger' on Ubuntu?

Tags: mongodb

I cannot use `wiredTiger` as a service for `MongoDB`.

Then, I progresses step by step according to the following guide;
 
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.0-upgrade/

Step-1: Start 3.0 mongod.OK, I did.
Step-2: Export the data using mongodump. OK 
Step-3: Create data directory for WiredTiger. OK - user permissions were adjusted.
Step-4: Restart the mongod with WiredTiger. OK

`mongod --storageEngine wiredTiger --dbpath <newWiredTigerDBPath>`
And yes, `mongod` worked. But the `Step-5` says that "Upload the exported data using mongorestore." However my console busy and says "waiting for connections on port 27017" because last command is not include a service like `service mongod start`.

Then I tried editing my `/etc/mongod.conf` file to run as a service. But I couldn't. I added wiredTiger director as dbpath. But I guess I need to edit `/etc/init/mongod.conf` file. Because it contains some codes that give permissions for db directory.

After I spent 8 hours I think there isn't enough documentation yet. And I want to ask;
What should I do for using wiredTiger on my MongoDB?
I'm wondering is there anybody who uses wiredTiger on MongoDB?

**console**
[image]

Comment: If you want to run mongo in the background add the --fork argument. This is what the service script will end up doing. Otherwise, if you are having problems with the mongod.conf file, please share the contents and any errors you get when trying to run service mongod start.

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't able to use wiredTiger upgrading MongoDB. However, today I uninstalled MongoDB 2.6 then installed MongoDB 3.0.3 . Immediate after the installation, I added `storageEngine=wiredTiger` on top of my mongod.conf file. Then I gave `sudo service mongod start` command and eventually I could.

---

**Edit:**

If the current version is supported the wiredTiger;

1. Get the backup of the current database using [mongodump](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/) command
2. Stop the mongod service using `sudo service mongod stop` command
3. Add `storageEngine=wiredTiger` text as the first line of `mongod.conf` file
4. Delete the all file on `/var/lib/mongodb` (or `/data/db` folder if used)
   [This is important. Because MongoDB cannot convert the current MMAP db files to wiredTiger format]
5. Start the mongod service using `sudo service mongod start` command
6. Restore the database from the backup using [mongorestore](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/) command
7. wiredTiger is being used...